# Laravel merge 3 queries and sort by date

Tags: laravel

Basically, I have this query, from my orders table and split it into 3 sub categories. I would like to merge these 3 sub queries into a single query and sort them by their date. is there any way to do this?

```
$query = \App\Order::where('company_id_for_user', $input['company_id'])->whereBetween('created_at', array($date_from_formatted, $date_to_formatted));
$order = $query->get();
$non_cr_order = $order->where('order_type', 'CR')->whereIn('status', $param);
$non_cr_order->all();
$online_order = $order->whereIn('order_type', $ord_type)->where('paid', 'Y')->whereIn('status', $param);
$online_order->all();
$paid_order = $order->where('order_type', 'CR')->where('paid', 'Y')->whereIn('status', $param);
$paid_order->all();
```

From here, I need a query, $total that has all 3 of the above merged in it, and sorted via date. how can i do that?

Comment: merge it by php code will be better.

Comment: any tips on doing so?

Comment: why you need to merge them>? i mean, what out put you want?

Comment: basically, i need the merged results to show the total from $non_cr_order, $online_order and $paid_order. that's why i split them up in the first place. so i need some form of indication as to where the totals come from. then sort them by date.

Comment: do for loop for each and count what you want.

Comment: figure out another way, laravel has a merge function that you could use on eloquent colelctions. so all i did was `$total = $non_cr_order->merge($online_order)->merge($paid_order)`

Comment: You can do this, only if they are same type collections.

Comment: For sorting just add `sortBy('created_at')` or `SortByDesc('created_at')` after `merge` method. Also check to remove duplicates there if any with `unique()` method. [sortBy](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-sortby), [sortByDesc](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-sortbydesc), [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-unique).